# Take characters of the string after a particular pattern and end it before the next pattern

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

I get the data with wget.

Example of the output:

`[{"id":15654014,"price":6.3e-06,"amount":1.7,"total":1.071e-05,"market":"somebtc","created_at":1622541615,"taker_type":"buy"}]`

The goal is to get the price value which is the `6.3e-06`, so the pattern is `"price":`, but the next pattern is to get everything until we reach `,` so we can be sure that we take only the price

My solution:

`cat price.txt | cut -c25- | sed 's/.//9g' > pricefin.txt`

So I basically remove the first 25 charachters and then remove everything except the first 9.

However the value of `6.3e-06` can be sometimes less or more than just **9**.

What can be the solution in my case?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your file is json file?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I safe it as .txt, but the data comes from some site's API so assume it's in JSON, but I am not really sure if it makes any difference as the output will be one string as I mentioned above in a .txt format

Comment: I suggest to use `jq` with JSON: `jq '.[].price' price.txt`

Comment: [tag:jq] is a BASH tool. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: @blockxyz: your example is valid JSON.

Comment: @Cyrus I made it to work, it saved a lot of clicky-clicky job for me also, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
sed 's/.*"price":\(.*\),"amount.*/\1/' your_file > new_file
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)`
- In this case its the stuff coming after `"price":` but before `,"amount`
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1`
- and put it into a new file